# How to connect a local hardhat contract with the new version of moralis stream?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, react, server-side, moralis

The server option has been removed from moralis which was easier to work with. But now it has a stream option. I have already set up the mongodb database, local server etc..

To create a new stream which wants to listen to the events, it needs the contract address and abi. But I haven't deployed the contract on testnet yet, I want to use the local hardhat contract address and abi. Can someone please tell how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The Streams API doesn't support local chains, you can view the [supported chains here](https://docs.moralis.io/docs/streams-api#supported-chains).

Comment: So I must deploy it first in goerli testnet and then use it?

Comment: Correct if you want to use the Streams API.